# Google Text-To-Speech volume for Spanish low, break the max threshold?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, volume, threshold

I am having trouble with an android device i am working on. I can successfully change the language on the device and English volume is great. But for some reason(even at max level) Spanish is extremely quiet. I have been trying to figure out a way to break the max threshold on the AudioManager and TTS but i cant seem to. Is there any advice you guys can give me.

Comment: Same problem here with Chinese. Any clues?